# Reference to Novalis in Ghérasim Luca's poem "La Poésie Pratique"

Tags: poetry, french-language, allusions, gherasim-luca

Ghérasim Luca's poem ["La Poésie Pratique"](https://www.poemes.co/la-poesie-pratique.html) / "Practical Poetry" contains the following lines:

> En pratiquant le bouche à bouche de mot à mot
> de « feu » le mort à « feu » vif
> d' « ellipse » géométrique en « ellipse » grammaticale
> **l'ellipse de flamme
>
> que
>
> Novalis mouilla jadis
>
> rallume ici**
> « le sale on »
> que l'Autre larron
> désespérait tant d'entrevoir
> « au fond du lac »
> illuminé

In English (translated by Google, as I'm not a native English speaker):

> Practicing mouth-to-mouth word-for-word
> from “fire” the dead to “fire” alive
> from geometric “ellipse” to grammatical “ellipse”
> the ellipse of flame
> that
> Novalis once dampened
> reignites here
> “the dirty one”
> that the Other rogue
> was so desperate to glimpse
> “at the bottom of the lake”
> illuminated

It's clear to me that Ghérasim Luca is proposing a new form of poetry. But overall, I found this poem very difficult to understand. Specially the allusion to Novalis ("l'ellipse de flamme / que / Novalis mouilla jadis /
rallume ici"). Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Bonjour and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This is an excellent question, but you are right, the translation is bad. I'm not qualified to translate French poetry, but I've corrected the more egregious errors, hopefully without introducing howlers of my own. With luck, a more skilled and fluent translator will happen along.

Comment: I assume it's a reference to a quote by [Novalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novalis), "_Water is a dampened flame_". No idea what the actual significance of this is in the poem's context.

Comment: “L’eau est une flamme mouillée” if you want to Google the original source. I also don’t know what it’s significance in the poem is.

Comment: And "Wasser ist eine nasse Flamme" in the actual German original (although maybe the French is more relevant for this poem).

Comment: Is "le sale on" wordplay on "le salon"? I suspect so. I don’t know French well enough to catch most plays on words in that language, though. I have no idea what "au fond du lac" could be, if it's a similar play on words.

Comment: But now that I've thought about it, maybe it's "eau font du lac". And I still have no idea how these plays on words fit into the poem.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks a lot! That's really helpful!